# report "ImportError: The nose module is not installed. It is needed for Theano tests." when use "theano.test"

Tags: python, theano, nose

When I use `theano.test()` to test the theano, it report：
`ImportError: The nose module is not installed. It is needed for Theano tests.`. But I check the package by `pip list`, I find that nose 1.3.7 is already exsist.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the Python version?

Currently, Theano Release 1.0 only supports >=3.4 and <3.6. If your Python version is higher than 3.5.X, try downgrading and then re-run the Theano test. Do let everyone know if that works.